# Fill a SELECT with JSON from a PHP File (AJAX REQUEST)

Tags: ajax, json, select, fill

I've been hours and hours (and time is running out to get this working) trying to figure out how to fill a select with the cities from a previously selected state using AJAX

the PHP file looks like this:

```
include_once("../models/class-Zone.php");

$state= $_GET["st"];

$cities= Zone::getCities($state);

echo json_encode($cities);
```

When I ALERT the result using ajax:

```
$.post(
        '../ajax/getcities.php?st='+stateid,
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
//I GET THIS:

[{"id":"08078","titulo":"BARANOA"},
{"id":"08001","titulo":"BARRANQUILLA"},
{"id":"08137","titulo":"CAMPO DE LA CRUZ"},
{"id":"08141","titulo":"CANDELARIA"},
{"id":"08296","titulo":"GALAPA"},
{"id":"08132","titulo":"JUAN DE ACOSTA"},
{"id":"08421","titulo":"LURUACO"}]
```

I haven't found a way to Iterate and fill a SELECT with this data. The select should look like this

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="ID FROM THE JSON">TITULO FROM THE JSON ARRAY</option>
    ... AND FOR THE REST OF THE RESULTS
</select>
```

Thank you beforehand! I am seriously confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the JSON first, then add HTML to the select for each city.

```
function(data) {
    var cities = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var c in cities) {
        document.getElementById('city').innerHTML += '<option value="' + cities[c].id +'">' + cities[c].titulo + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, you're awesome... It worked! That's all I have to say. I've been programming for 3 years and I learn and re-learn everyday!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using jQuery, so I think you can easily iterate the JSON in your success callback

```
function(data){
    var st=""
    for(i in data){
        st+="<option id='"+data[i].id+"'>"+data[i].titulo+"</option>"
    }
    //here st contains all the options
    // you just have to append it in your select's html
    // I don't know your DOM structure, so if you didn't have anything 
    // you can add the select, then display it
    $("thePlaceWhereYouWantIt").html("<select>"+st+"</select>")
    }
```

It should work, but it depends on your actual HTML

Good luck